# I wanna bucket fill an image but getting how to do it

Tags: flutter, flutter-custompaint

I am able to color the house but the problem is when i try to color a different section pervious color is being disappear. but the color is being removed when i try to color in different section. I have tried everything i could think of but i am not able to get it need some help here

```
Color _fillColor = Colors.cyan;
bool selected = true;
class houseFiller extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<houseFiller> createState() => _houseFillerState();
}

class _houseFillerState extends State<houseFiller> {
  final notifier = ValueNotifier(Offset.zero);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (e) => notifier.value = e.localPosition,
      onPointerMove: (e) => notifier.value = e.localPosition,
      child:  Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _fillColor = Colors.brown;
              });
            },
            child: const Text(
              "Brown",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.brown)),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _fillColor = Colors.amber;
              });
            },
            child: const Text(
              "Amber",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.amber)),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _fillColor = Colors.cyan;
              });
            },
            child: const Text(
              "Cyan",
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.cyan)),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: houseFillerPainter(notifier),
              child: const SizedBox.expand(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  Offset toLocal(BuildContext context, Offset position) {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    return renderBox.globalToLocal(position);
  }
}

class Shape {
  Shape(strPath, this.label, this.color,this.selected) : _path = parseSvgPathData(strPath);

  /// transforms a [_path] into [_transformedPath] using given [matrix]
  void transform(Matrix4 matrix) => _transformedPath = _path.transform(matrix.storage);

  final Path _path;
  Path? _transformedPath;
  final String? label;
  final Color? color;
  bool selected=false;
}

class houseFillerPainter extends CustomPainter {

  houseFillerPainter(this._notifier) : super(repaint: _notifier);
  static final _data =
  '''m829.35 691.34.96 21.77h-33.58l-1.01-23z,m829.35 691.34-33.63-1.23 4.15-2.05 34.26 1.03 1.37 22.38-5.19 1.64z,
  m818.5 506v7l-20.53.49 16.34-1.82s-.41-8.7 0-8.29 4.19 2.62 4.19 2.62z,m810.96 497.49-39.34-25.66v-2.25l47.98 31.72.13 1.92-5.82-3.81-1.55 7.79z,
  m810.53 462.36.91 16.29-4.37-2.75-.58-12.26z,m810.01 500.25v9.52l-22.5 1.84-.7-10.22z,m810.01 500.25-23.2 1.14-1.13-16.46z,
  m802.04 311.49 6.31 8.56-32.84 5.78-.45-9.98.13-.01z,m802.04 311.49-26.85 4.35-.13.01-.23-4.92.19-.01 24.48-2.86z,m773.08 272.22 26.42 35.84-24.48 2.86-.19.01z,
  m808.35 305.61-20.19-25.76 3.12-2.45 4.22 4.83 2.94 3.38.67-17.55 9.24 12.03z,m797.97 513.53-10.25 1.14-.21-3.06 22.5-1.84 4.3 1.94z,
  m794.83 618.53 5.04 69.53-4.15 2.05 1.01 23-33.63 7.33-.76-3.5-4.84-93.36h12.08v-4.66l21.01-.39z,m793.76 604.32.09-.01.13 1.87h-.07l-52.27-11.84-.12-2.63z,
  m781.65 240.57 10.85 17.74-1.22 19.09-3.12 2.45-24.39-31.14 4.73-3.7 6.58 7.82 6.57 7.81z,m787.72 514.67 6.13 89.64-.09.01-52.24-12.61-1.01-20.67 45.34 12.26-.17-3.12-5.7-99.18 5.7 3.93 1.13 16.46.7 10.22z,
  m810 500.25-24.33-15.32-5.67-3.93-1.84-1.26-6.52-4.49v-3.41l39.36 25.65 1.4 9.71 1.55-7.79 5.82 3.81.62 10.23-1.89-.45v-7s-3.78-2.16-4.19-2.56 0 8.29 0 8.29l-4.3-1.94z,
  m775.51 325.83 7.17 134.73-3.79-2.39-1.94-26.81-1.44-.06-7.01-165.28 4.58 6.2 1.75 38.71.23 4.92z,
  m772.86 481.65v11.88l-25.52 1.36v-11.88z,m771.62 471.83v3.41l-35.21 3.41-1.84-44.62 8.12-.72 26.48-2.31 6.34.3 1.44.06 1.94 26.81 3.79 2.39 24.39 15.34 4.37 2.75-.91-16.29 6.74 3.8 2.33 35.14-47.98-31.72z,
  m769 617.09-2.46.35h-2s-.75-.14-.83-.35-.6-7.84-.6-7.84l26.47-2 1 11.32-21 .39z,m767.12 218.26 1.38 26.75-4.73 3.7-3.98-5.08-1.26-1.62-.01-.01.18-35.16z,
  m761.08 248.25 47.26 59.8v12l-6.3-8.56-2.54-3.44-26.43-35.83-4.57-6.22-5.68-7.71-1.16-1.29s-.41-6-.47-8.12a2.39 2.39 0 0 0 -.11-.63z,m763.17 609.25a3.07 3.07 0 0 0 -1.78-.47 10.38 10.38 0 0 1 -3.48 0 19.2 19.2 0 0 0 -4-.65h-4.38l-2.17-.7v-9.48l42.3 9.29z,
  m761.25 272.56.19 3.78-25.23 2.46-3.01-2.81z,m760.77 262.97.48 9.59-28.05 3.43v-13.02z,m762.82 258.31 5.68 7.71 7.01 165.28-6.34-.3-7.73-154.66-.19-3.78-.48-9.59v-1.52l-4.15-3.14z,
  m758.7 206.84-.18 35.16-15.01 1.37-20.52-27.81z,m760.77 262.97h-27.57l-66.66-83.09-.53-31.17 76.41 102.03 13.64-2.18.56 9.75 4.15 3.14z,
  m750.67 513.18-10.16-5.25-.96-3.28 11.12 5.52z,m742.42 610.21-.78-15.87 52.27 11.84h.07l.85 12.35h-4.24l-.95-11.32-42.3-9.3v9.49 4.17z,
  m747.34 483.01-10.93-4.36 35.21-3.41 6.52 4.49-.65 1.26-4.63.66z,m756.06 248.56-13.64 2.18-76.42-102.03-.2-4.71 77.2 102.65 15.52-1.65 2.56 3.24a2.39 2.39 0 0 1 .11.65c.06 2.11.47 8.12.47 8.12l1.16 1.29h-6.2z,
  m743.37 394.14-.2 2.39-9.28-6.31-1.22-4.92z,m726 610-23.61-.28.75-11.82 5.49-2.26 10.37 1.61 1.18-2.92-1.32-3.5s-9.14-11.06-15.42-11.87l-3.07 3.42-.43-10 2.54-.11 38.03-1.27 1 20.67.12 2.63.78 15.87z,
  m740.51 571.04-38.08 1.23v-3.69l38.22-1.36 2.07.59 9.16 2.64 33.8 9.73.17 3.12z,m733.68 502.87-1.49 2.25-21.84-9.69-1.22-4.71z,m727.07 439.55 2.31 6.69-27.09-18.36 3.35-2.32z,
  m726.18 437.09-1.84-52.6 1.59-3.71-22.16-20.78 1.33 7.88 1 55.68zm7.82 127.61-2-58.07-20.47-9.15 1.09 60.86zm-1.76-59.58 1.49-2.25-24.55-12.15 1.22 4.71zm1.7-114.9 9.28 6.31.2-2.39-10.7-8.84zm6.62 117.7 10.16 5.26v-3l-11.12-5.52zm-34.87-82.36-3.35 2.32 27.09 18.36-2.31-6.69zm-32.46-209.48.55 20.33-6.38-7.11-.86-49.42 66.66 83.12v13l3 2.81 25.23-2.46 7.74 154.65-26.48 2.31v-34.43l-8.18-6.35.06 41.5 1.84 44.62 10.93 4.35v11.88l25.51-1.36v-11.87l4.64-.66.65-1.26 1.86 1.27 5.7 99.18-33.8-9.73-1.75-54-9.62-5.73 2.21 57.12-2.07-.59-38.22 1.36v3.69l-2.54.11-13.73-319v-19.59c.24-6-3.11-21.29-6.6-22.38s-6.35 4.64-6.35 4.64zm54.77 119.41-2.87-7.78-1.63-53.46 1.86-1.27-22.36-27.98 1.09 7.37 2.19 57.05-3.09 1.14z,
  m725.93 380.78-1.59 3.71-19.24-16.59-1.33-7.88z,m702.99 245.01 22.33 27.97-1.86 1.27-19.39-21.87z,m720.13 594.33-1.18 2.92-10.36-1.6-26.83-4.11-1.85-.39 1.93-9.03 18.66 4.39 18.32 4.32z,
  m718.81 590.83-18.32-4.32-.17-4.13 3.07-3.42c6.28.81 15.42 11.87 15.42 11.87z,m708.59 595.65-5.49 2.26-21.44-3.62.1-2.75z,m705.73 732.95.94 7.99-14.26 3.62-26.62-1.84v-15.15l9.22-1.63 30.01 1.08z,
  m703.17 310.57 3.09-1.14 18.83 18.28 2.87 7.78z,m702.35 613.17-14.79-.78 1.77 30.43h13.1zm0-3.43 23.65.26 4.72 112 31.66-5.11.76 3.5-57.41 12.61-.73-6-30-1.09-9.22 1.63v15.15l-6.78 1.87v-6.76l-4.9-118.88h.39a7.15 7.15 0 0 0 1.57-2.54c.14-.95 0-4.63 0-4.63l-23.06-1.48 2.53 7.85 4.84 122.55-24.29 6.55-5.46-140.56h8.73v-10.92l55.48 3.79 6.65.81.21-6.05 21.44 3.63z,
  m681.34 265.16-126.34-134.77-290.42 82.55v3.06l-18.23 327.54h4.3l308.69-21.6s132.45 38.06 132.45 37.46l1.51.42zm4.82-11.79 13.73 319 .43 10-141-34.4-336.82 19.1 17.92-366 314.25-91.85z,m684.9 395.56.79 18.02-128.19-84.98-297.86 52.07 1.24-21.66 296.42-53.34z,
  m669.47 261.05 10.03 10.03-8.46.82-1.66 2.35z,m674.07 424.3.07-10.03 11.05 7.11v.01l-7.73.76-1.23 2.15z,m673.57 583.26 1.23 16.27-55.48-3.79v-9.23z,m599.29 584.35-.44 4.02-.82-21.5 75.54 16.39-54.25 3.25z,
  m669.38 274.25-24.65 10.11-8.23-5.81v-.01z,m669.38 274.25-32.88 4.29-6.53.86-8.46-4.5 41.11-7zm667.54 424.65 6.49 4.76-37.31 1.59-12.28-3.12z,m667.4 229.3-1.39-1.55-.98-49.78 1.51 1.91z,m666.01 148.71.53 31.17-1.51-1.91-.62-31.41z,
  m665.03 177.97.98 49.78-6-6.68-1.58-51.32z,m665.8 143.96.21 4.75-1.6-2.15-.1-4.58z,m664.41 146.56.62 31.41-6.6-8.22-1-32.51z,m664.31 141.98.1 4.58-6.98-9.32-.15-4.62z,m661.9 253.37.72 14.53-41.11 7v-13.24z,m589.54 178.35 72.36 75.02-40.39 8.29-68.78-59.51 37.22-7.32z,
  m742.96 246.65-77.16-102.69-1.49-1.98-7.03-9.36-1.58-2.1-98.06-130.52h6.27l159.08 215.56 20.52 27.81 15.01-1.37.01.01 1.26 1.62 3.98 5.08 24.39 31.14 20.19 25.76v2.45l-47.27-59.81-2.56-3.24z,m658.43 169.75 1.58 51.32-1.97-2.2-1.43-51.39z,m657.43 137.24 1 32.51-1.82-2.27-.91-32.53z,
  m657.28 132.62.15 4.62-1.73-2.29v-4.43z,m656.1 611.78s.14 3.68 0 4.63a7.15 7.15 0 0 1 -1.57 2.54h-.39l-18.64-.8-2.5-7.88z,m654.53 133.38-101.26-133.38h4.37l98.06 130.52v4.43z,m655.7 134.95.91 32.53-22.17-27.64 20.09-6.46z,m553.27 0 101.26 133.38-20.09 6.46-103.76-129.36-230.03 79.07.43-9.94-1.78-2.19-5.19-3.54 210.99-73.88z,
  m646.25 462.22-2.11 2.36-15.35-7.12-1.59-5.02h2.25z,m641.64 305.77-.82 3.9h-1.86l-15.03-12.9-1.43-5.33h2.56z,m640.81 309.67.83-3.9-16.58-14.33h-2.57l1.44 5.33 15 12.9zm-110.53-111.67 1.09.72 8.94 5.88 12.42-2.45 68.78 59.51v13.24l8.46 4.5 6.53-.86 8.23 5.81 24.65-10.11 1.62-2.34 8.46-.82 5.2 119.81-46.76-32.72-.81-46.46-12.69-11.26.82 48.86-24.22-16.94v-49l3.86-4.56-43.51-40.58h-3.17l3.93 11.3v55.64l-4.24-3-89.62 15.73.67-78.82 2.67-5.7v-3.59l-95.91 21.91v2.36l6.38 5.31v73.67l-121 21.25 7.71-134.63 6 3.69v8.53l12.83 11.46 210.71-55 .27-.3 15.84 14.22z,
  m635.15 162.85v3.14l-.71 4.92-12.39-13.52-2.32-10.77z,m658 218.87-59.39-66.15v-23.56l3.27-2.81-44.24-53.63 2.94 10.64.39 27.4-4.62-5.15-86.6 25.2v-1.32l-.47-60.73 4.29-11.53-99.03 34.77 9.72 4.48-.87 59.47-86.66 25.21 3.92-91.6 230-79.07 103.79 129.36 22.17 27.63zm-27.53-35.41c.15-.4 0-11.05 0-11.05l-9-9.42.55 13s8.35 7.88 8.49 7.47zm-8.45-26.07 12.38 13.52.71-4.92v-3.14l-15.42-16.24z,m624.44 414.37 42.45-4.2.65 14.48-43.1 3.23z,
  m609.24 446-4.45 3.58-39.27-16.8-.44-.19-3.9-11.46z,m644.14 464.58 2.11-2.36-16.8-9.78h-2.25l1.59 5zm-13.14 71.81-70.91-20.69-89.93 6.35-6.62-7.38.61-89.65 7.92-10.65-106.17 12.55 9.11 9.66-1.95 85.47-4.4 7.16-118 8.32 8.61-150.18 11 4.91 9 9.19 207-32 2.76-.41 26.76 15 17-2.84 18.21 4.27 15.58-2.07 57.9 31v13.51l12.24 3.09 37.28-1.59v-5.11h2.16l1.23-2.15 7.73-.76.83-.09 5.77 132.82-47.08-13.74-1.33-72.88-13.93-6.59zm-64.23-20.39 40.06 12-2-78.4 4.45-3.58-48.06-24.87 3.9 11.46.45.19z,m604.9 278.8-3.86 4.56-38.89-33.84-3.93-11.3h3.17z,
  m557.64 72.72 44.28 53.63-3.27 2.81-38.07-45.8z,m598.03 566.87.82 21.5h-4.09l-5.63-1.33-1.74-2.56v-19.45l3.26-.77 3.02 12.63 2.98-10.42z,m597.84 562.33 77.79 18.32 3.36 14.78.92-4.28 1.85.39-.1 2.75-.21 6.05-6.65-.81-1.23-16.27-75.54-16.39-1.38-.4z,
  m593.48 379.83-26.94 3.57h-.01l-15.58 2.07-18.21-4.23 51.52-6.94z,m593.48 379.83-.05-17.15 73.46 47.49-42.45 4.2-57.9-30.97z,m669.79 255.92 9.77 10.26-.06 4.9-10.03-10.03-.09 13.2-6.76-6.35-.72-14.53-72.36-75.02-1.21-.29 1.5-6.15 74.42 78.19 2.16 16.36z,
  m591.08 776.9v19.24l-449.34-40.14.41-15.77 9.52-139.65 11.36.45-.11-17.94 54.56-3.09-.81 15.56 14.74-.42 38.48 1.43v-17.41l214.83-11.16.32 16.47 28.24 3.89 21.09-1.84 2.46 185.87zm-120.37-58.34-7.51-11.18.45-97.11 6.1-10.71-108.63 2.05 8.46 9.69-.92 92.83-10.75 10.34zm-224.36-102.15 5.52-9.2-83.87 2.65 4.71 8.39-4.71 79.85-8.19 9.2 89.19 3.7-8.19-10.24z,
  m589.95 194.83-37.22 7.32-12.42 2.45-8.93-5.88 49.87-11.27 7.26 7.06z,m589.13 587.04-47.06.71-7.7-1.22 53.02-2.05z,
  m587.39 565.03v19.45l-53.02 2.05v-18.52z,m587.39 565.03-53.02 2.98-28.66-6.66 54.25-1.84z,m674.14 414.27-.07 10.03-.04 5.11-6.49-4.76-.65-14.48-73.46-47.49.05 17.15-9.22-5.53-.19-18.12 2.36-.39 2.46 14.63 3.46-14.53 76.19 50.09 2.5 17.67 1.69-14.93 12.96 8.52-.5 4.14z,
  m584.07 356.18.19 18.12-51.52 6.94-.22-16z,m584.07 356.18-51.55 9.06-28.03-17.55 53.17-9.12z,m581.04 169.13.21 18.32-49.87 11.27-1.1-.72 1.36-14.54z,
  m554.12 140.58 26.92 28.55-49.4 14.33-26.96-28.56z,m562.15 305.16 38.89 27.2v.01l24.22 16.94 12.68 8.86 46.76 32.72.2 4.67-127.6-89.89-296.42 53.34.27-4.69 120.95-21.25 86.2-15.14 89.61-15.73z,m545.83 762.68v6.37l-9 3.35-2.46-185.87 7.7 1.22z,m534.37 568.01v18.52l-28.66-2.87v-22.31z,
  m534.37 586.53-21.09 1.84-28.24-3.89 20.67-.82z,m532.74 381.24-17 2.84-26.76-15 6.63-.97 9.44-1.38z,m504.68 154.9 26.96 28.56-1.36 14.54-26.92-24.47z,m530.28 198-15.76 4.3-15.84-14.22-10.35-9.29 15.03-5.26z,m559.96 559.51-54.25 1.84-2.89-1.34 1.61-3.47 55.67-3.1 29.63 6.98.92 3.84-3.26.77z,
  m505.1 0-210.99 73.88v-2.32l200.89-71.56z,m504.49 347.69 28.03 17.55.22 16-27.69-14.51z,m505.05 366.73-9.44 1.38-.75-5.16 7.1-16.36 2.53 1.1z,m554.12 140.58-49.44 14.32-1.32 18.63-15.03 5.26h-.01l-2.67.94-.51-19.81 2.41-1.44 6.7 11.16 8.1-20.08 52.28-14.61 28.91 30.36 2.93 20.4 1.86-7.65 1.21.29.41 16.48-1.44-.32-7.26-7.06-.21-18.32z,
  m557.66 338.57-53.17 9.12-2.53-1.1 1.93-4.43 53.75-9.09 28.07 18.46.72 4.26-2.36.39z,m498.68 188.08-.27.3-210.71 54.99-12.83-11.46v-8.53l-6.01-3.69 216.28-59.77.51 19.81 2.67-.94h.01z,m487.27 562.07 7.59 15.05 7.96-17.11 2.89 1.34v22.31l-20.67.82-.32-16.47-.09-4.61z,m495.61 368.11-6.63.97-2.76.41-.16-18.28 1.98-1.05 6.82 12.79z,
  m486.06 351.21.16 18.28-207 31.95-8.98-9.18-10.98-4.91z,m485.44 345.28 2.6 4.88-1.98 1.05-226.8 36.14.22-3.86z,m482.58 0-299.96 107.17 2.18-25.38 222.44-81.79z,m473.57 57.23-4.29 11.53-85.02 27.71-9.72-4.48z,m472.07 414.37-7.92 10.65-89.14 11.56-9.11-9.66z,m471.63 229.82v3.59l-2.67 5.69-86.86 20.3-6.38-5.31v-2.36z,
  m463.2 707.38 7.51 11.18-112.8-4.09 10.75-10.34z,m463.55 514.67 6.61 7.38-101.5 7.16 4.4-7.16z,m469.75 599.56-6.1 10.71-94.07 1.03-8.45-9.69z,m299.3 77.42 1.78 2.19-.43 9.94-3.92 91.6-7.96 2.31 5.34-109.58z,
  m291.44 72.52 2.67-.96v2.32l-5.34 109.58-2.91.85z,m291.44 72.52-5.58 111.79-25.22 7.34 4.97-109.93v-.01z,m485.09 154.38 2.46 4.1-2.41 1.44-216.28 59.77v-4.91z,
  m269.89 579.15v17.4l-38.48-1.43-.21-18z,m269.89 579.15-38.69-2.03 253.43-13.72.09 4.61z,m679.56 266.18-9.77-10.26-3.38 10.55-2.16-16.37-74.42-78.19-1.5 6.15-1.86 7.65-2.93-20.4-28.91-30.31-52.28 14.6-8.1 20.09-6.7-11.16-2.46-4.1-216.23 60.4-4.28 1.17v-3.09l290.42-82.52 126.34 134.77 12 294.66-1.51-.42v-5.28l-5.83-132.82-.33-7.72-.78-18-.2-4.68-5.2-119.81z,
  m262.59 85.62-.78 17.28-72.99 25.09-15.75-10.58z,m261.81 102.9-1.17 26.32-66.49 22.51 5.93 4.92-3.68 66.73-5.33 7.16 45-10.85q-.24 5.43-.51 10.85l-51.83 12.83-20.2 10.69 9.56-136.65 15.73 10.59z,m257.81 192.47 2.48-55.25.35-8 1.17-26.32.78-17.28.13-2.87 2.89-1.03-4.97 109.93z,
  m260.64 129.22-.35 8-60.21 19.43-5.93-4.92z,m685.69 417.24-12.96-8.52-1.69 14.93-2.5-17.67-76.19-50.09-3.46 14.53-2.46-14.63-.72-4.26-28.07-18.46-53.75 9.09-1.93 4.43-7.1 16.36-6.82-12.79-2.6-4.88-225.96 38.21.16-2.82 297.86-52.07 128.19 84.98.33 7.72-.83.09v-.01z,
  m251.87 607.21-5.52 9.2-73.69 1.84-4.71-8.39z,m559.34 521.94-308.69 21.6v-6l118-8.32 101.5-7.16 89.93-6.35 70.92 20.68 13.67 4 47.08 13.74v5.28c.04.59-132.41-37.47-132.41-37.47z,m246.35 543.54 18.23-327.51 4.28-1.25v4.91l-7.71 134.63-.27 4.69-1.24 21.66-.16 2.82-.22 3.86-8.61 150.18v6.01z,
  m240.82 700.75 8.19 10.24-89.25-3.69 8.19-9.2z,m667.4 229.3 6.38 7.11 12.38 13.79v3.17l-131.53-144.15-314.25 91.85-3.5 1c.07-1.39.13-2.78.2-4.18l20.75-5.45 2.82-.82 25.22-7.34 2.91-.85 8-2.31 86.66-25.21 86.36-25.13 86.6-25.2 4.62 5.15 37.68 42 59.3 66.14 2 2.2 6 6.68z,m236.45 211.1c-.13 2.86-.26 5.73-.4 8.59l-45 10.85 5.33-7.16z,
  m163 262.48 71.85-17.79q-.34 7.27-.69 14.51l-53.55 12.08z,m180.64 271.28 53.55-12.08-1.19 25.59-48.27 10.21 7.58 5.73-2.58 69.6-7.65 10.31 46.6-8.05q-.28 5.79-.58 11.58l-54.62 8.06-20.48 12.5 10-142.26h.1z,m233 284.79c-.12 2.44-.24 4.9-.36 7.36l-40.3 8.61-7.61-5.76z,m230.66 571.85 254.38-14.22 2.23 4.44-2.64 1.33-253.43 13.72-2.46-1.16z,
  m229.06 364.82c-.12 2.6-.26 5.21-.38 7.8l-46.6 8.05 7.65-10.31z,m154 414.12 73.2-11.19c-.16 3.09-.31 6.16-.46 9.25l-53.89 8.06z,m226.69 412.18q-.94 18.51-1.88 37l-50.12 5.19 8.33 5.19-4.65 76.55-8.45 9.83 50.08-4.23q-.37 7-.74 13.91l-57.45 2.45-20.63 15.52 11.13-159.22 1.65-.25 18.84 6.12z,m224.82 449.17c-.11 2-.2 3.92-.31 5.89l-41.51 4.49-8.33-5.19z,
  m675.62 580.65-77.78-18.32-1.19 4.14-3 10.43-3-12.64-.92-3.84-29.64-7-55.66 3.11-1.61 3.47-8 17.11-7.59-15-2.23-4.48-254.34 14.22-1.92 4.15-6.55 14-2.31-10.55-1.52-6.92.9-16.92q.38-6.95.74-13.91l.45-8.48q2.06-39 4.06-78.17c.11-2 .2-3.93.31-5.89q.93-18.5 1.88-37c.15-3.09.3-6.16.46-9.25.06-1.31.14-2.6.2-3.91q.36-7.41.74-14.82.28-5.79.58-11.58c.12-2.59.26-5.2.38-7.8q1.8-36.29 3.55-72.67c.12-2.46.24-4.92.36-7.36l1.22-25.59q.34-7.24.69-14.51c.06-1.5.14-3 .21-4.53l.45-9.62q.27-5.41.51-10.85c.14-2.86.27-5.73.4-8.59s.28-6 .42-9l3.5-1-17.92 366 336.83-19.08 141 34.4.17 4.13-18.65-4.39-1.93 9-.92 4.29z,
  m216.66 595.54.82-15.56 2.4-.52 2.31 10.54 6.55-14.04 2.46 1.16.21 18z,m220.45 533.23-.45 8.48-50.07 4.22 8.45-9.83 42.06-2.87z,
  m219.26 555.62-.9 16.92c0 .78-.08 1.54-.13 2.32l-76.83 6-.47-3.7.25-3.53 20.63-15.52z,
  m182.62 107.17 299.96-107.17h12.42l-200.89 71.56-2.67.96-25.83 9.19v.01l-2.89 1.03-99.21 35.34v-3.27z,
  m235.09 240.16-71.58 18.84h-.34l.34-4.91 20.2-10.69 51.83-12.83z,m163.51 259 71.58-18.84c-.07 1.52-.15 3-.21 4.53l-71.88 17.79h-.1l.24-3.5z,
  m163.51 118.09 99.21-35.34-.13 2.87-89.52 31.79-9.73 3.1z,m162.92 583.12.11 17.94-11.36-.45-10.28-.39.45-15.89z,m158.41 188.38-3.43 47.15-23.01 7.15-3.39 45.59 23.08-7.09-23.08 317.56 1.29 1.09 11.52.39 10.28.39-9.52 139.65-56.7-7.17 10.85-159.25-17.61 1.43 27.44-371.13 52.27-15.76z,
  m153 404.73 20.5-12.47 54.62-8.06q-.37 7.41-.74 14.82l-74.78 11.41z,m154 414.12-1.65.25.27-3.94 74.74-11.43c-.06 1.31-.14 2.6-.2 3.91z,
  m141.4 580.82 76.83-6c.05-.78.09-1.54.13-2.32l1.52 6.92-2.4.52-54.56 3.14-21.08 1.21z,m152.31 414.37-11.13 159.22-.25 3.53.47 3.7.44 3.51-.45 15.89-11.52-.39-1.29-1.09 23.08-317.56 3.32-45.65 3.43-47.15 4.93-67.87 9.73-3.1-9.56 136.65-.34 4.91-.24 3.5-9.95 142.26-.4 5.7z
  '''.split(",");

  final _shapes = [
    Shape(_data[0], '', const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[1], '', const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[2], '', const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[3], '', const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[4], '', const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[5], '',const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[6], '', const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[7], "", const  Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[8], "",const  Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[9], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[10], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[11], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[12], "",  const Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[13], "", const Color(0xffc8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[14], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[15], "", const Color(0xffc8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[16], "", const Color(0xffc8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[17], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[18], "", const Color(0xffc8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[19], "",const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[20], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),

    Shape(_data[21], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[22], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[23], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[24], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[25], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[26], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[27], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[28], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[29], "", const Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[30], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[31], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[32], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[33], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[34], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[35], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[36], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[37], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[38], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[39], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),

    Shape(_data[40], "", const  Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[41], "", const  Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[42], "", const  Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[43], "", const  Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[44], "", const  Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[45], "", const  Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[46], "", const  Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[47], "", const  Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[48], "", const  Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[49], "", const  Color(0xffacd266),false),

    Shape(_data[50], "", const  Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[51], "", const  Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[52], "", const  Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[53], "", const  Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[54], "", const   Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[55], "", const Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[56], "", const  Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[57], "", const  Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[58], "", const  Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[59], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),

    Shape(_data[60], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[61], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[62], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[63], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[64], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[65], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[66], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[67], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[68], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[69], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),

    Shape(_data[70], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[71], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[72], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[73], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[74], "", const  Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[75], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[76], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[77], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[78], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[79], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),

    Shape(_data[80], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[81], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[82], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[83], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[84], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[85], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[86], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[87], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[88], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[89], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),

    Shape(_data[90], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[91], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[92], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[93], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[94], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[95], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[96], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[97], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[98], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[99], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),

    Shape(_data[100], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[101], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[102], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[103], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[104], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[105], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[106], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
    Shape(_data[107], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[108], "", const Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[109], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[110], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),

    Shape(_data[111], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[112], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[113], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[114], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[115], "", const  Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[116], "", const Color(0xffed1e29),false),
    Shape(_data[117], "", const Color(0xff0c8c44),false),
    Shape(_data[118], "", const Color(0xffacd266),false),
    Shape(_data[119], "", const Color(0xfffff),false),
  ];

  final ValueNotifier<Offset> _notifier;
  final Paint _paint = Paint();
  Size _size = Size.zero;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (size != _size) {
      _size = size;
      final fs = applyBoxFit(BoxFit.contain, const Size(750.22101, 750.22101), size);
      final r = Alignment.center.inscribe(fs.destination, Offset.zero & size);
      final matrix = Matrix4.translationValues(r.left, r.top, 0)
        ..scale(fs.destination.width / fs.source.width);
      for (var shape in _shapes) {
        if(_shapes.isNotEmpty) {
          shape.transform(matrix);
        }
      }
    }

    canvas
      ..clipRect(Offset.zero & size)
      ..drawColor(Colors.white, BlendMode.src);
    List<Path>? selectedShape;
    for (var shape in _shapes) {
      final path = shape._transformedPath;
      selected = path!.contains(_notifier.value);
        _paint
          ..color = (selected == true ? _fillColor : shape.color)!
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
        canvas.drawPath(path, _paint);
        // selectedShape ??= selected ? shape : null;

        _paint
          ..color = Colors.black
          ..strokeWidth = 3
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
        canvas.drawPath(path, _paint);

      }
    if (selected==true && _paint.color==const Color(0xffacd266)) {
      _paint
        ..color = Colors.black
        ..maskFilter = const MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.outer, 12)
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
      Matrix4? matrix;
      for(var e in selectedShape!) {
        print("Vhitra aayo");
        canvas.drawPath(e, _paint);
        print("THis is e ${e}");
      }
      _paint.maskFilter = null;
      final builder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(ui.ParagraphStyle(
        fontSize: 32,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      ))
        ..pushStyle(ui.TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white70,
          shadows: kElevationToShadow[1]!+kElevationToShadow[2]!,
        ));
        // ..addText(selectedShape._label);
      final paragraph = builder.build()
        ..layout(ui.ParagraphConstraints(width: size.width));
      canvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, _notifier.value.translate(0, -32));
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

#This is the code the only problem is that pervious color is being disappear. And i doesnt want that to happen. I want to pick color like multiple color and color colors in different section of house

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### PROBLEM:

When you change Shape color you do not hold this value. Then you select another shape and old shape goes to default color.

---

### ADVISE:

I assume that, you select color by button, then click shapes and fill those shapes with selected color. And if you click second times to shape with same color then shape **should return** to its default color. Otherwise we never go back to default color if default colors not on buttons.

---

### SOLUTION:

**1-** Change your **Shape** class. We need selected color, isSelected parameter, default color on shape.

```
class Shape {
  Shape(strPath, this.label, this.defaultColor, this.isSelected, this.selectedColor)
      : _path = parseSvgPathData(strPath);
  final Color? defaultColor;
  bool isSelected=false;
  Color? selectedColor;
...
```

example of Shape

```
final _shapes = [
  Shape(_data[0], '0', const Color(0xffacd266),false, null),
  Shape(_data[1], '1', const Color(0x000fffff),false, null),
...
```

**2-** Do not use **setState** on your color choose **TextButtons**, we do not need this, we just need to set _fillColor thats all.

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () { _fillColor = Colors.brown; },
...
```

**3-** change **Paint** function and assign isSelected and selectedColor on Shape.

```
canvas
    ..clipRect(Offset.zero & size)
    ..drawColor(Colors.white, BlendMode.src);
List<Path>? selectedShape;
for (var shape in _shapes) {
  final path = shape._transformedPath;
  selected = path!.contains(_notifier.value);
  if(selected == true){
    // if shape selected before and try to fill with same color again,
    // i assume that this means back to the default color,
    // otherwise we never go back to default color if default colors not on buttons
    if(shape.isSelected == true && shape.selectedColor == _fillColor){
        shape.isSelected = false;
        shape.selectedColor = null;
    }else{
      shape.isSelected = selected;
      shape.selectedColor = _fillColor;
    }
  }

  _paint
    // if selected then selected color otherwise default color
    ..color = (shape.isSelected == true ? shape.selectedColor : shape.defaultColor)!
    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
  canvas.drawPath(path, _paint);
```

I tested it and it seems to work. Let me know if it is work or not :)

---

Comment: everything works fine except for one thing when i select a button the color automatically fills a path of house

Comment: It did not happen on me, did you check 2. step on my response. If you use setState on  TextButton's onPressed it can happen because you draw page again when you click button. Did you delete setState from all TextButton's onPressed?

Comment: yes i deleted it and everything is working but when ever i press on a path color is being filled on another path

Comment: I think it is about your calculate problem. You need to fix on there.  but also will fix if you take your SizedBox after all buttons in your build.

Comment: Because your data and calculations are designed to be drawn at the top of the page, but the buttons are at the top of the page. For this reason, there is a shift from the shape you clicked down as much as the button areas.  You need to fix this calculation or you can fix if you take your SizedBox after all buttons in your build. i mean draw shapes at the top of page

Comment: Thanks it works and everything is fine can u give me one more hint like the image with path is made up of 5 color and when i color one path and i want that same selectedcolor to be colored on other path which has same default color @Ugur Aydogdu